# Can Eclipse Highlight global variables?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, netbeans

Netbeans has a useful feature I haven't seen in other editors: suppose you have:

```
(function() {
    var a=3,
    b=5,
    c=7
    d=8

}) ()
```

(or any other script that accidentally creates a globally-scoped variable instead of a local variable)

Netbeans will make the global variable a purple color, warning that it is a global. I haven't seen this in Eclipse JS editor, or even the demo of professional Komodo IDE.

Is there any plugin/addon that will enable this variable highlighting in Eclipse (or other IDE?)

While I like the Netbeans features, unfortunately Netbeans 7.x has been extremely slow, and its fonts and other UI elements are [notoriously ugly on Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390057/how-to-fix-netbeans-7-4-ugly-text-and-popups-in-ubuntu-13-10).

Answer (score 0):

You can set Eclipse to flag a warning or error against the variable if it is hiding a global variable (i.e. it has the same name). However I cannot find a way of having global variables highlighted differently to local variables.

Comment: For this and other reasons, I find Eclipse to be a much worse web-development platform than Netbeans. Too bad Netbeans freezes up once in awhile.